# debconf-set-selections does not work in Dockerfile

Tags: debian, mysql, docker

I'm trying to set a root password for a mysql database in a Dockerfile like this:

```
(short version)
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
RUN echo mysql-community-server mysql-community-server/root-pass password 'mypassword' | debconf-set-selections && \
echo mysql-community-server mysql-community-server/re-root-pass password 'mypassword' | debconf-set-selections
RUN apt-get install mysql-server...
```

When I try to do it in a KVM it works perfectly, but somehow my root password is not accepted in the docker conainer - in the log files I see, that an empty root password has been set.  I also tried without the `ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive`. Does anyone has an idea?